# Update a view during a server process

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Scenario:

- I have a WCF service in a machine that is not my web server.
- In the web site I have a request that calls the WCF service.
- During that request I want to update a "progress bar" because the process with WCF service will happens in parts (the process will send data in batches).

My question is: how can i update the view (progress bar) during a process in the server side?

Comment: Nope, what is SignalR? (looking for SignalR...)

Comment: This is exactly what you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852586.aspx

Comment: @SteveB, put you comment as a answer and i will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dino Esposito has discussed this specific case in the [march 2012 issue of Msdn Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852586.aspx).

To summarize its article, you can use [SignalR](http://signalr.net) which is a client/server messaging framework. It works over multiple "transports", depending on the server and client abilities (websockets, iframe, etc.) to have a pseudo persistent connection.

This framework is used to allow the server to report progress to the client, which can update its ui (typically the progress bar).

Comment: That said, I believe SignalR is very promising for several scenarios, because it allows sending messages from the server to the client. This is a feature that will become very important in the futures years. Moreover, the guys behind the project are Microsoftees, and I'm confident the work done with signalr will be sooner or later integrated in the .Net framework itself.

Answer (score -1):

The scenario that you describe seems suitable for a call back wcf service. Please, refer to the following URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx for details.

Comment: The problem is not with WCF service, I mentioned the WCF service only to understand the scenario. My problem is with async request from the server to client (talking about asp.net mvc level).

Comment: Well, then your whole question is wrong. The scenario, and hence my answer, was based on the WCF service. It is unfair to vote my answer down when your scenario list WCF as the first requirement.

Comment: When I mentioned WCF was only to understand the scenario. But the problem is not with WCF, but with update a view during a process in server, that in this case is a WCF, but could be a simple process in the web server. What I want is update the view, update a progress bar in the view. Look to the topics when I use "I have" and "I want". So, the question is not wrong, as you can see, Nick and Steve (in the question comments) understood exactly my question.

Comment: Your actual question reads: "My question is: how can i update the view during the process with the WCF service?". Also, "I have" means you already have something. When you say "I have a WCF service in a machine that is not my web server." it means that it is already being used. Now to want to update the view, you can use the call back behavior to do exactly that. That is what my answer explained.

Comment: You forgot of the Step 3... but to take off the ambiguity, i will edit the last line. ^^